# React: background image overlaps navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

Hi I am developing a react project.
In App.js,

```js
return (
  <HashRouter>
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Navigation />
  </HashRouter>
);
```

and I added an background image in about.js

```css
.background {
  background-image: url('../source/loyoalfree.jpg');
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Then I could still see the navbar
but can not click the navbar any more.
I think the background image covers the navbar.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Share your `about.js` code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a z-index to your image.

```
.image { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  /* your remaining css*/
}
```